# composer to disable https completely

Tags: ssl, https, composer-php

my network does not work well with https, so doing

```
composer.phar install
```

throws

```
  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                         
  The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto  
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

i used

```
{
    "packagist": false
},
{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "http://packagist.org",
    "options": {
        "ssl": {
            "verify_peer": "false"
        }
    }
}
```

as a http falback, but again it crashes in some other point:

```
Installing dependencies
  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.4.0)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         
    Downloading: 100%         



  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                          
  The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Translation/zipball/0919e0fc709217f8c9e5049f2603419fdd4a34ff" file could not be downloaded: Failed to   
  enable crypto                                                                                                                                     
  failed to open stream: operation failed
```

my problem is just with TLSv1, previous SSL versions should work, as the browsers work correctly.

how should i do, the problem also exists in other cmd tools that depend on https like npm, bower, git, curl, ...

Comment: why `"packagist": false`? what does that do?

Answer (score 46):

```
composer config --global disable-tls true
composer config --global secure-http false
```

Answer (score 17):

You can turn off TLS (For your specific project) using your composer.json as such:

```
{
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.43"
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "disable-tls": true,
        "secure-http": false
    }    
}
```

**NB**: Take not of the **"disable-tls": true** in the config section.

Comment: still it is not working after updating above config.. I am getting same error

Comment: Are you using a proxy server to access the internet? 
You might want to set the proxy in your command prompt as such:

set HTTPS_PROXY=[IP:PORT]

before retrying your composer.

Comment: No.. I am not using any proxy

Answer (score 10):

The problem is simply that you wrapped `"false"` in quotes, which is [`true` when converted to `bool`](https://3v4l.org/jdSAX).

Use `"verify_peer": false` instead of `"verify_peer": "false"`:

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "http://packagist.org",
      "options": {
        "ssl": {
          "verify_peer": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's okey.
It will work. You just have a mismatch:

```json
"options": {
    "ssl": {
        "verify_peer": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

in order to disable https totaly (not recommanded)
you need to add "secure-http": false in your composer.json file config key like this:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    },

    ...

    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "bin-dir": "vendor/bin/",
        "secure-http": false
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Comment: I just learned that on newer composer versions (e.g. 2.2.7) while using packagist (default with composer), [the additional step to use http for packagist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63506182/367456) is required as well. The settings given here are fine however with composer 1.10.6 from what I can see (only tested with global composer config).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable SSL with Composer. Even if it works like in your setup, you cannot control the source URLs of any package you use. Some of them do not offer anything without SSL, so you MUST use SSL.

I think it's the best idea to make SSL work. Did you try `composer diag` and see where the problem is?

Comment: `composer diag` throws exaxtly the same error:

`[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed`

Comment: "Make SSL work" is the only solution I have for you. I cannot help you with that because I don't know what is broken, but if other tools are also broken, then some basic element is to blame, i.e. a shared library or something like that.

Comment: the problem is not my machine specific, there is a proxy or something in my internet path that prevents proper TLS negotiation,
and blaming this proxy will not solve my problem, i need a working solution!

Comment: I have to repeat myself: Your internet connection is broken. Fix the proxy or whatever is interfering. I'd consider it inacceptable to not be able to use the latest TLS 1.2 version if I so desire. And effectively it will not help you to disable SSL in Composer or downgrade to SSLv3 because you cannot control the server having the sources you need. If there is no non-SSL URL available, or it does not allow using SSLv3, then it will never work anyway.

Comment: this problem exists for so many people already and it has been so for at least months for each of them. I'd rather disable ssl verification and get on with my work thank you

Comment: "I have to repeat myself: Your internet connection is broken."

This shows a lack of basic understanding of how corporate proxy systems and firewalls work. These services often perform man in the middle attacks on all SSL traffic and inject their own self signed certificates. There's not really anything you're gonna be able to do to convince a SecOps team or a WAF team to do to "fix" the connection. It's like that by design.

Comment: Working for a corporation that I'd consider both security-aware and not doing these things invalidates your "lack of basic understanding" part, I think. If any interception proxy is really doing man-in-the-middle, the security department should really be able to give you the "fake CA" root certificate to install it and then be able to use it without having to "disable HTTPS" or "disable HTTPS certificate validation", just like they did with any of your corporate-provided browsers. Talk to security, point out the problem and ask for support - it will increase the chance for solutions.

Comment: In many places, It is against policy (and sometimes security software!) to install ANY additional certs on the work stations, so no. This is not a viable answer in many environments.

Please refrain from declaring how it should be and stick to actually answering the questions. There could be reasons for not doing it 'your' way, not all of which the users can post online, so making assumptions does not work for anyone.

Comment: By the way, ZSscaler is a data filtering service corporations can use to monitor outgoing traffic for potential data loss. How it works is essentially a man in the middle attack turned to corporate use. But because of how it works, it generates it's own SSL certs on the fly. What comes along with said certs? Brand new signatures. Signatures that FAIL the check that composer does to verify that the transfer was secure. Ergo, with zscaler, you have to turn https off, or turn verify-peer off.

Your 'solution' does not work for all environments Sven.

Comment: As I said before: You cannot make external packages be offered using HTTP by simply disabling TLS. I don't care what your corporate network does - however if they actively prevent you from getting work done, start talking to that department to work something out that works for you.

You ruled out "install something on the corporate computer", you ruled out "a way around that proxy with MITM TLS", and yes, I would consider any of these things not a solution. TALK TO SECURITY! Illustrate your problem. You cannot work like that, find a solution that works for them and for you.