# How to enable ssl protection in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, composer-php

After running `composer update` I got this problem:

> You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled. [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
> curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL ce
> rtificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
> require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] []...

Comment: Do you get this error on your local machine, when entering the command? Is there any hard Firewall or something, which can result in this error? Please provide some more information.

Comment: i am working on a laravel project and when i run composer update locally i get the problem

Comment: Is openssl installed? If not then you may need to re-install curl after installing it

Comment: @apokryfos how to install it

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? How is this even related to Laravel itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase i don't know the resson

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well there could be multiple issues with your environment, which does not allow SSL connections, since the tool cannot accept the certificates.

Another approach could be to turn off the SSL verification, as long as you working on a development machine.

```
composer config --global disable-tls true
composer config --global secure-http false
```

You find other possibilies to set the settings in your project [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921486/composer-to-disable-https-completely).