# how to solve "you are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled"? in Laravel

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I'm running the project in laravel, but when I type "composer" the yellow statement "You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled" keep showing, can someone know how to remove or resolve it? thank you so much

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921486/composer-to-disable-https-completely

Comment: Also, why not **enable** SSL simply? There's a good reason that this warning is shown